# bulk conversion of textures, using DirectXTex Texconv, in the command line

Tags: linux, unix, command-line

Im able to use the following command - as shown in the [documentation](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTex/wiki/Texconv) - to convert textures individually

```
texconv -pow2 -f BC1_UNORM cat.jpg
```

However I'd like to convert a whole folder full of textures. Following [this advice](http://www.gamedev.net/blog/1865/entry-2259778-compressing-bulk-of-textures/) I've tried using a wild card and the file directory:

```
texconv.exe -pow2 -f BC1_UNORM somepath\*.jpg
```

but the command prompt says

```
reading somepath\*.jpg "FAILED" <8007007b>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that I have never used `texconv`, this may not be the most efficient way of doing things, but it should work.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Set IFS to newline
SAVEIFS=$IFS
IFS='
'
for i in $(echo *.jpg); do
    texconv -pow2 -f BC1_UNORM $i
done
# Restore IFS
IFS=$SAVEIFS
```

The `SAVEIFS` and `IFS` variables are related to bash's [internal field separator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_field_separator).
In the code above, I'm replacing the default `IFS` to contain only `\n`(newline)

The loop goes through each file matching the pattern `*.jpg` and feeds that as input to `texconv`

Comment: Hi looks good, but unfortunately when I paste it in to the command line I [get this](http://imgur.com/Fjz2hnF). Im a newby, so you'll probably have to tell me so the "commands" are not recognised because im missing something?

Comment: Your original question is very misleading. Particularly with the tags you've set. You've tagged the post as `linux`, `unix` but you're using Windows to test it. I don't know the for loop syntax for Windows. I wanted to clarify this right when I saw the `texconv.exe`, but I presumed you just pasted it from the documentation

Comment: Apologies, I assumed cos directXtex is windows and I have Linux style command line tools installed it would be ok.

Comment: It should be ok..but it looks like your shell is not interpreting the commands like a normal linux shell. Usually, `#!/bin/bash` should tell the shell to execute the file using `/bin/bash`

Comment: I need to add Cygwin to the Windows Environment Variables, so I can run Unix in cmd. Then your solution should work